# how to add variable hour

Tags: python, odoo

I would like to add a variable to add start time and end time, but until now I can only add it through datetime and I do not want that variable because it asks me to add date and I just want the time.

```
class reserva (models.Model):    
     _name='gimnasio.reserva'    
     tipo_reserva=fields.Selection([('clase','Clase'),('evaluacion','Evaluacion')])    
     fecha_reserva=fields.Date()    
     hora_inicio=fields.Datetime()
     hora_termino=fields.DateTime()
```

Comment: Have you considered just storing the hour as an integer in the range 0...23 (inclusive)? Or do you need hour, minute, second, and millisecond?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#timefield

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/time-field-in-odoo-124037
Try looking at this maybe if you edit the question i can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a float field with `float_time` widget in the view, it will display the float number as time.

Python:

```
hora_inicio= fields.Float(
    string='hora de inicio',
)
```

View:

```
<field name="hora_inicio" widget="float_time"/>
```

Comment: so it's friend, at the end use a float as hour